# Create a div with a fixed bottom that uses up the rest of the space

Tags: html

I'm making some mobile HTML & would like to have a div that uses up 100% of the space it has, but not use up its container and in it have 3 divs that split it up into 3 parts and have the following layout:

[image]

How can I do this using divs, I've tried to but having percentage and fixed height divs is confusing. I can do it with horizontally aligned ones, but vertically it confuses me. I don't want it to overlap by making the bottom one absolute.

***Edit***

The remaining space is essentially just one big div that has an `overscroll-y` that uses up the whole space

I have to place the layout in the section underneath the titlebar which is why I cant use `position: fixed` because it will interfere with the parent container.

[image]

Comment: I'll go ahead and suggest `display:table`/`display:table-row`

Comment: The classic solution is `position:fixed` and proper margins to the main content

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for! But how would I make the middle one use the rest of the space

Comment: I could use position: fixed, but it won't work with different sized devices. The above element is still in another div and I don't want it to go into that one

Comment: What you want is a sticky footer and the content to stretch if it's less than the browser height. Give me a few I'll throw some code together.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hKQnX/

Comment: You can use `position:fixed` with `bottom:0`

Comment: IMO, for mobile, I would use a fixed on the header but make it very small (20-40 px). That's what you usually see on mobile.

Comment: @EricLemos thats almost exactly perfect!! Its just using fixed it will overlay into its parent container

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NQ76p/

Comment: what is overlaying into the parent container?

Comment: Using `position:fixed`, `top:0` that div will overlay itself into the parent sencha view, which contains a toolbar. The whole layout is not using the entire screen only a section underneath the toolbar

Comment: is the toolbar fixed?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear with the parent container

Comment: Check my answer. You can place the fixed bar above the wrap and add `margin-top:-` the size of your toolbar.

Comment: @Eric It doesn't look like its fixed, its part of the sencha touch framework  so its all generated via javascript during rendering time so I can't touch that bit, the only place I can put raw html is in the gray area in the screenshot which runs to the bottom of the screen

Comment: Use Jquery Mobile - suggestion

Comment: I thought about jquery mobile & I did compare the two when deciding to use sencha, sencha had this javascript mvc pitfall but it wouldn't stutter as much on android devices so it gave a better end user experience

Comment: The recent jquerymobile 1.3 won't either. It's been totally upgraded. I really don't think we should be re-inventing the wheels when there is a workable solution. Why not try it? http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/

Comment: I think using http://jsfiddle.net/hKQnX/ and adding in the header height as the top might work great, @EricLemos you should give this as an answer

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen its more than that, I've already dug deep enough to change & there are a couple of plugins on availed to me with sencha such as the slide navigation and date picker which can make the user feel like s/he is using a native application. This is still lacking a bit in jqm where I feel its a web app with certain elements

Comment: Well it still boils down to you can still use fixed. You might have a point there anyway, although Jqm does have a date picker. Glad to know one of our answers worked even though all pointed to the very same direction.

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen thank you. I will just add the height of the toolbar and use that as `top`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the image in your edited question probably came from JQuery Mobile. Consider using jQuery mobile. It could be an option too.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;  background-color:#ddd; z-index:1;}
    #header{position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 80px; background-color:#f30;z-index:3;}
    #footer{position: fixed; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%;  height: 80px;  background-color:#f30;z-index:4;}
    #content{width:100%; z-index:5; padding-top: 90px; padding-bottom: 80px;}
</style>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="content">
    Put body content here...

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

</div>
```

You might need jQuery to spice it all up. This should give you the basic idea.

Comment: How do you prevent the overlap?

Comment: In the middle im going to place a div which has an overscroll so it has to use 100% of that space, in this the footer will have overlap with the middle section

Comment: I have updated with a style that adds a padding top and bottom. You could use margins too. Set that to 80px or higher

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wy6rS/1/

```
<div id="toolbar">This is fixed toolbar.</div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">This is the header</div>
      <div id="content">Content will Expand with scripting. Notice the push.</div>
        <div id="push"></div>
  <div> <!--wrap ends here-->
<div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
```

The push makes room for the sticky footer. Notice equal negative margin on #wrap.

```
#wrap { width:100%; min-height:100%; height:100% !important; margin-bottom:-80px; margin-top:50px; }
#toolbar { position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; height:50px; }
#header { height: 140px; }
#content { min-height:300px; height:100%; }
#push, #footer { height:80px; } /* Must be same height as footer */
```

Then you'll need script to expand the content. Check the jsfiddle. It will work in a real page.